# New features announcement / app cue

Tags: tooltips, features, visual-cues

I am working on the announcement of new features for our existing portal users. The announcement will be made by displaying a distinctive modal element that is triggered by some specific events. Through this element, the user can either upgrade, get more info or close the modal by clicking a standard icon. The question is if there is any pattern/research about how many times this element can be displayed before the user considers it annoying? How insistent should we be promoting new features? I am sure you know what I am talking about :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, once is too many times for me! Just have it tucked away in a "whats new" page and let the user subscribe to email updates if they want to be kept in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the way it is being done now a days **Don't show again** button. I mean there should be 3 buttons on modal.

1. More ( on clicking it, user should get info and a link to upgrade)
2. Dismiss ( dismissing for now )
3. Don't show again (or wait for next major upgrade)

And product should display this modal everytime on start of the product unless button 3 is clicked.

Hope this helps. Thanks.